# How to use order by desc clause in spring framework with mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I've tried doing it both ways. I noticed that when I remove the DESC my values appear again, when I put the DESC the values do not appear, but it also does not display any error message.

Example 1:

```
                        order by field_01 DESC,  
                        case  
                              when field_02='a' then 1  
                              when field_02='c' then 2  
                              when field_02='b' then 3  
                        END
```

Example 2:

```
PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize,(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "field_01")));
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're saying, how does a values appear/disappear by adding/removing `DESC` in `ORDER BY`? Also, the order is valid with or without `DESC` so of course you'll not get any error..

Comment: Hello, what happens is that when I add the DESC I don't receive any data. When I remove the DESC the data reappears.

Answer (score 1):

create a sort type object and use that like:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("field_01").descending();//for  descending

Sort sort = Sort.by("field_01").ascending();//for  ascending

PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize,sort);
```

Comment: I'm using Pageble this way, but it only works when I do ASC.
When using DESC, no value is retrieved from the database.

`PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(pageNumber, pageSize, Sort.Direction.DESC,"created");`